# Trouble parsing JSON with the GSON lib

Tags: android, json, gson

I am having a hard time parsing a JSON response I am getting from a web server. Here is the relevant bits of code that I am using:

Method that gets the JSON response:

```
void readResponse(String response)
{       
    Log.w("Rakshak", "In the in the new user: "+response); <-- log entry posted below
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    NewUserModel newUser = gson.fromJson(response, NewUserModel.class);

    Toast.makeText(this, newUser.firstName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); <-- this dosent show
    Log.w("Rakshak", newUser.getFirstname());<-- no log entry here
    Log.w("Rakshak", newUser.firstName);    <-- no log entry here           

}
```

The log from the first line on the "readResponse" method:

```
05-20 19:56:10.963: W/Rakshak(8519): In the in the new user: {"id":18,"username":"Rakshak","password":"[password]","firstName":"Rakshak","lastName":"Raghavan","created":"2014-05-20T14:26:10+0000","updated":null}
```

And now the NewUserModel class: (This is where I think the problem is)

```
public class NewUserModel {

public String id;
public String created;




/*
 * All the set methods
 */

@Expose
@SerializedName("username")
public String username;
public void setUsername(String s) 
{
    this.username = s;
}

@Expose
@SerializedName("password")
public String password;
public void setPassword(String s) 
{
    this.password = s;
}

@Expose
@SerializedName("firstName")
public String firstName;
public void setFirstName(String s) 
{
    this.firstName = s;
}

@Expose
@SerializedName("lastName")
public String lastName;
public void setLastName(String s) 
{
    this.lastName = s;
}

/*
 * All the get methods
 */


public String getId() { return id; }

public String getUsername() { return username; }

public String getPassword() { return password; }

public String getFirstname() { return firstName; }

public String getLastname() { return lastName; }

public String getCreated() { return created; }



}
```

Why cant I get stuff off the JSON? The Toast and 2 log's after the `NewUserModel newUser = gson.fromJson(response, NewUserModel.class);`dont do anything. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are not getting the object newUser created fromJson().

Comment: Isn't that what this line does? 'NewUserModel newUser = gson.fromJson(response, NewUserModel.class);' Is there somethinkg else I show be doing?

Comment: fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT) - This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the specified type. Second arguement is TypeOfClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i too have got this type of error when using GSON Library.

you can try like this.

```
Type modelType = new TypeToken<NewUserModel>() {}.getType();
    NewUserModel newUser = gson.fromJson(response, modelType);
```

Hope it helps.